# Why is my DIV overlay not working?

Tags: jquery, html, css

On my website http://www.robertbradley.co.uk/gallery/portrait-photography/ there is a small preloader image that loads - although its CSS properties are absolute - it seams to be put behind the next div that loads

the code im using is

**DIV**

```
<div id='preloader2'>
<img src="<?php echo THEMEROOTURL; ?>/img/preloader.gif">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#preloader2 {
    position:absolute; 
    left:50%; 
    top:50%; 
    margin:-15px 0 0 -15px;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    opacity: 0.6; 
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=60);
}
```

Can someone please help me?

**Update:** Sounds strange but I need my preloader to stay infront so I can hide/unhide it later when an image is clicked

Thanks

Comment: In my opinion you should get rid of the splash page. What does it add? Give your users the content right away.

Comment: @Bookcasey or at the very most, store in session/storage their click so they don't have to do it everytime.

Comment: The preloader comes up but I need it to stay infront.. of the content because I want to hide and unhide it later when an image is clicked - I plan to loose the splash page - good tip

Comment: Or at least a skip intro link.

Comment: Well z-index certaily brought it to the front - only issue is it seams to be doing strange things to the other div's - looks like im gonna have to do a bit more investigating

Comment: well make sure you give z-index to all elements outside the flow. So all elements that are positioned absolute or fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `z-index` (in CSS) of the absolute positioned element to a higher number than your other elements.

Comment: In the end i got it working - was just a case of messing with jQuery to set the z-index at different points - Thank you Horen